# Remove white space (CSS) - Chrome & Safari OK - Firefox NOT

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

after searching and trying for about 2 hours I decided to ask you. If I call my website with Google Chrome or Safari I do not have this issue.

But if I call my website with Mozilla Firefox, I see a little white space between my 3 social media links and the next row.

Test it by yourself. Does it works with Chrome/Safari and does Firefox have a problem?

https://gamekeys-shop.de/

Can somebody tell me how I can fix that? - I do not understand why there is a difference between those browsers...

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `display: inline-block;` from the following selector: `a.ubtn-link`

Comment: I can not remove it, because I use WordPress. But I can change it. To what should I change the `inline-block`?

Comment: You can use `block`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has its own default stylesheet. Try using CSS reset (resets default CSS) and your problem should be solved.

To use CSS Reset, include the following source file in your web page:

Answer (score 0):

at BODY tag set the line-height to zero.

like this:

```
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-14 gecko osx wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-5.0.1 vc_responsive" style="line-height:0;">
```

Or do it in your custom .CSS file.